# How does end() work for animate()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, chaining, jquery-chaining

I'm currently looking into chaining my jquery code. An element needs to ditch a border, animated. My solution: animate the borderWidth to zero and then remove the class:

```
$(".imgWrap", element).animate({ borderWidth: "0px" }).end()
    .removeClass("border");
```

animate() is supposed to return the wrapped element, but what I understand from the jQuery API, `end()` will return the object to its state before the call to `.find`.

`.find` is in the context of the example so I took the liberty to replace it with `.animate`. Alas, this does not work for me. The result of `.end()` is the result of `.animate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you (now) have no `find` filter (or any other filter), `end` has nothing to undo. It has nothing to do with `animate`.

If you were to first select a container, then look within it for `imgWrap`, you could undo the filter:

`$('.container').find('.imgWrap').animate({borderWidth: '0px'}).end();`

The above will return the elements matching `$('.container')`, as the `find` is *undone* by `end`

What may be confusing things is that if you chain `removeClass` immediately after `animate`, `removeClass` will not wait for `animate` to finish so it will appear that there is no animation happening. You need to remove the class in the `complete` function of `animate`:

```
$(".imgWrap", element).animate({ borderWidth: "0px" }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('border');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.end()` returns the *jQuery* object to its state before `.find()`

i.e. if I do this:

```
$('div').find('.class').end()
```

then what's left after chaining is the result of `$('div')`.  It doesn't change anything about the elements themselves.

The jQuery object returned by most jQuery methods not only contains the current matching elements, but also contains a stack of the results from previous chained calls.

Hence when you call `.find()` the previous list is still stored on that stack.  Calling `.end()` just removes the last item from the stack.

To fix your actual problem (i.e. changing a style *after* the animation has finished) you need to put that change in a [`complete` callback function parameter](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to `.animate()` itself.

```
$(".imgWrap", element)
   .animate({ borderWidth: "0px" }, function() {
       $(this).removeClass("border");
   });
```

Comment: Together with adam's almost identical answer another jquery lesson thanks!